# How do I check if my multi-threading program works properly in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#define MAX_THREADS 1

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


DWORD WINAPI printNumbe(LPVOID);

// We need an array of Handles to threads
HANDLE hThreads[MAX_THREADS];
//...an array of thread id's
DWORD id[MAX_THREADS];
//And a waiter 
DWORD waiter;

DWORD WINAPI printNumber(LPVOID n)
{

int num = (int)n;

for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    cout << "Hey there!" << endl;
}

return (DWORD)n;
}

//get ready, because here's where all the REAL magic happens
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

int number;

cout << "Please enter a number:" << endl;
cin >> number;

//here is where we call the CreateThread Win32 API Function that actually
//creates and begins execution of thread
//please read your help files for what each parameter does on
//your Operating system.

//Here's some basics:
//Parameter 0: Lookup, 1: Stack Size, 2: The function to run with this   thread, 3: Any parameter that you want to pass to thread
//function, 4: Lookup , 5: Once thread is created, an id is put in this variable passed in

hThreads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, printNumber, (LPVOID)number, NULL, &id[0]);

//now that all three threads are created and running, we need to stop the primary thread
// which is this program itself - remember that once "main" returns, our program exits
//so that our threads have time to finish. To do this, we do what is called "Blocking"
//we're going to make main just stop and wait until all three threads are done
//this is done easily with the next line of code. please read the help file about the specific API call
//"WaitForMultipleObjects"

waiter = WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

//after all three threads have finished their task, "main" resumes and we're now ready 
//to close the handles of the threads. This is just a bit of clean up work.
//Use the CloseHandle (API) function to do this.

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
{
    CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Hi all. Recently I've started taking Operating System class at my college. 
I got some chance to learn about threads and multi threads. My professor gave me a power point slide with some sample codes on how to start multi-threading program in C++.

So I have decided to use his code as the base and decided to tweak it a bit so that I can understand it better.

Please disregard all those comments I made (most of comments don't apply to this program, those comments were basically in the slide and I just left it there as a reference).

SO I've tweaked to produce "Hey there!" "x" times depends on what number the user inputs into "x". As you are seeing, I made it to print inside printNumber function (sorry about the name, since my main assignment is on printing prime numbers , so forgive me about that).

So the program runs fine and exactly produces "Hey there!" multiple times.

But here's the question. Since my professor wants me to use multi-threads, how do I verify myself in C++ that the program in running with a multi-thread?

This program seems like printing "Hey there!" in a row (just like under a single thread) and there's no way I can tell if multi-threading has been applied to the program or not.

Keep in mind that, I am not that familiar with those syntax and it's my first time using WINAPI in C++ as well as first time doing threading programming.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Print `GetCurrentThreadId` inside `printNumber`, each thread will have a separate id.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have included inside both main and printNumber function and they happened to have different Id, which I believe it means they are running on different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) will return the unique id for the current thread, if you print this inside your threaded function and `main` you should find it returns different values.